# Header file error: expected identifier or '(' before numeric constant

Tags: c, compiler-errors, header-files

I'm new to header files and am not sure why I am getting this error. The first piece of code is from the relevant header file, and gives the expected identifier error:

```
#define MAX_ADDR_LENGTH 1000
struct listNode{
  char addr[MAX_ADDR_LENGTH];
  struct listNode *next;
};
```

Related to this, there is another error in the file relevant to that header, which gives me a "note: in expansion of macro 'MAX_ADDR_LENGTH', which it gives me on the line which gives the declaration of int MAX_ADDR_LENGTH:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "header.h"

char *crawl(char* getLinksFrom, int hopTo){

int MAX_ADDR_LENGTH = 300;
char startAddr[MAX_ADDR_LENGTH];
char destAddr[MAX_ADDR_LENGTH];

}
```

I've tried a number of things hoping it was just a small oversight (removed the #define altogther, deleted the line that gives the int MAX_ADDR_LENGTH declaration, just deleted the phrase 'int' from the same; all of which just caused even more errors).

Answer (score 2):

The problem: ‘MAX_ADDR_LENGTH’ is defined twice in your code; Once as a Macro and once as a variable.

Try to delete the statement declaring MAX_ADDR_LENGTH as a variable.

Comment: Got it. So I did that and it got rid of the original errors. But made a ton of new ones, relating to dereferencing

Answer (score 0):

Build your header like this:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

#define MAX_ADDR_LENGTH 1000
typedef struct _listNode{
  char addr[MAX_ADDR_LENGTH];
  struct _listNode *next;
} listNode;

#endif /* HEADER_H */
```

and use it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "header.h"

char *crawl(char* getLinksFrom, int hopTo){

    char startAddr[MAX_ADDR_LENGTH];
    char destAddr[MAX_ADDR_LENGTH];
    .... more code
}
```

The `#ifndef`...`#endif` construct is called an [include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard). It's not necessary to get your code compiled, but good practice to use it.

The typedef is used to define the node structure. It does not create a variable yet, it's just defining a type named `listNode` that you can use to build your list later on.